# Deposition of Aluminium Nitride is giving me a range of colors. Why?

Tags: experimental-technique

I have been trying to deposit Aluminium Nitride via RF Sputtering at certain conditions and the resultant thing I have is a range of colors from blue to brown [image]at the substrate holder. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely optical interference at thin films, similar to what you see when an oil film is present on water. For thin films the optical transmission depends strongly on thickness and wavelength. For varying thickness varying color is observed.

Answer (score 1):

To enlarge on my2cts' answer, note also that as the thickness of the film increases, the cycle of colors is repeated over and over again in the same order. By noting how many cycles are present and the color of the film at a specific point on the workpiece, the film thickness at that point can be estimated. This is a common technique in the thin film deposition world.

For those of you who ride motorcycles, this phenomenon is the reason why the chrome on your exhaust header pipes gets discolored: the hot exhaust toasts the chrome, causing the growth of a *native oxide* on top of the chrome whose thickness can be deduced by noting the color. A skilled mechanic can tell in this way what the exhaust temperature has been and thereby tell whether or not your carbs are set too lean.